# How the sender can see its own messages too with socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm using socket.io and I want to send a message to a specific user by its `socket.id` and that the sender will see its own message too. I get the `socket.id` and sending the message by:
`socket.to(msg.id).emit('chat message', msg.message);` which `msg.id` is the `socket.id` of the recipient.

I found out that I can't get a message with `socket.to(<socketid>).emit('hey', 'I just met you');` where `<socketid>` is my own.

This is the part from the server that I get the message and send it to a specific user:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    socket.to(msg.id).emit('chat message', msg.message);
  });
});
```

How can I make it that the sender will see its messages too, not just see messages from others?

Hope you can help me with that.

Comment: `socket.emit('chat message', msg.message);` should emit it back to the sender.

Comment: instead of socket.to(<socketid>)?

Comment: Why dont you just use the message u typed to input or whatever form control you are using and append it to your messages array or the output div u want to display it too

Answer (score 0):

Please check this...

I hope it help you

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) { 
  socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {   
    socket.broadcast.emit('chat message', {
      userid: socket.id,
      message: msg
    });
  });
```

Comment: and what in the client side? 
socket.emit('chat message',  'some text'); this?